# Rotate Longtable with Break

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating

I wonder how to rotate a longtable like this?

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please avoid external links that could break in the future and write a proper, self-contained question. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that your question is duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683226/.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has given no indication that the screenshots posted in the query were actually created in LaTeX. In case they were, one might try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{<column spec>} % e.g., '{ l *{9}{c} }'


...
\endfirsthead

\endhead     %% Empty header from page 2 onward
\endfoot     %% No footers
\endlastfoot

% body of table:
...

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```