# border line not complete tabularx latex

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a table but their two problems:

- the border line is not completed
- If I add caption the table confused

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\scalebox{0.7}{
%\caption{Result of all evaluation metrics in \cite{lim2023robust}}
%\label{table2.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|lllll|}
\cline{1-7}

%\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Dataset}                                                                 & \multirow{2}{*}{Evaluation metric} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Machine learning models} \\
\cline{3-7}
                                                                                      &                                    & LR     & NB     & RF    & XGBoost & SVM RBF \\
                                                                                      \cline{1-7}
\multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Training set\\cross-validation\end{tabular}} & Mean AUC                           & 0.992  & 0.990  & 0.994 & 0.994   & 0.992   \\
                                                                                         & Mean Sensitivity                   & 0.968  & 0.975  & 0.975 & 0.973   & 0.968   \\
                                                                                         & Mean Specificity                   & 0.963  & 0.956  & 0.962 & 0.963   & 0.965   \\
                                                                                         & Mean accuracy                      & 0.966  & 0.966  & 0.968 & 0.968   & 0.966   \\
                                                                                         & Mean average precision             & 0.979  & 0.973  & 0.980 & 0.981   & 0.968   \\ \cline{1-7} 
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test 1 evaluation\end{tabular}}          & AUC                                & 0.990  & 0.986  & 0.993 & 0.994   & 0.991   \\
                                                                                         & Sensitivity                        & 0.928  & 0.936  & 0.928 & 0.936   & 0.936   \\
                                                                                         & Specificity                        & 0.963  & 0.960  & 0.963 & 0.963   & 0.963   \\
                                                                                         & F1 score                           & 0.913  & 0.914  & 0.913 & 0.918   & 0.918   \\
                                                                                         & Accuracy                           & 0.945  & 0.948  & 0.945 & 0.949   & 0.949   \\
                                                                                         & Avg .Precision                     & 0.970  & 0.951  & 0.975 & 0.976   & 0.970   \\ \cline{1-7}
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test 2 evaluation\end{tabular}}             & AUC                                & 0.988  & 0.982  & 0.989 & 0.992   & 0.990   \\
                                                                                         & Sensitivity                        & 0.937  & 0.945  & 0.945 & 0.945   & 0.937   \\
                                                                                         & Specificity                        & 0.961  & 0.961  & 0.963 & 0.963   & 0.963   \\
                                                                                         & F1 Score                           & 0.915  & 0.920  & 0.923 & 0.923   & 0.919   \\
                                                                                         & Accuracy                           & 0.949  & 0.953  & 0.954 & 0.954   & 0.950   \\
                                                                                         & Avg .Precision                     & 0.964  & 0.960  & 0.968 & 0.972   & 0.965   \\ \cline{1-7}
\multirow{6}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test 3 evaluation\end{tabular}}             & AUC                                & 0.987  & 0.972  & 0.987 & 0.991   & 0.986   \\
                                                                                         & Sensitivity                        & 0.913  & 0.921  & 0.921 & 0.937   & 0.921   \\
                                                                                         & Specificity                        & 0.966  & 0.958  & 0.966 & 0.966   & 0.966   \\
                                                                                         & F1 Score                           & 0.910  & 0.903  & 0.914 & 0.922   & 0.914   \\
                                                                                         & Accuracy                           & 0.940  & 0.940  & 0.944 & 0.952   & 0.944   \\
                                                                                         & Avg .Precision                     & 0.961  & 0.936  & 0.958 & 0.965   & 0.946 \\
                                                                                         \cline{1-7}
                                                                                         
\end{tabularx}
}
```

[image: I uploaded the picture that describe problem 1]

How can I solve problem?
And how I add caption without confusing the table?

Thanks

Comment: tabualrx should always have an X column (and avoid using \scalebox on tables, it will always produce inconsistent font sizes). unrelated but why are you nesting `tabular` here `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}` a one-row one column tabular does nothing useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the missing border-line issue, you need to change

```
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Machine learning models}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Machine learning models}
```

To use `\caption` and `\label` commands, you would need to embed these commands along with the `tabularx` environment in a `table` environment.

However, don't just apply these simple fixes. Instead, I'd like to encourage you to streamline and simplify the tabularx material so that it has a chance of fitting inside the width of the text block, making a call to `\scalebox` unnecessary. Getting rid of all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines in the table would also be very much appreciated by your readers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' column type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horiz. rules (\toprule, etc)

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt

\caption{Result of all evaluation metrics in \cite{lim2023robust}}
\label{tab:results}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CCCCC @{}}
\toprule
Evaluation metric & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{Machine learning models} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-6}
& LR & NB & RF & XGBoost & SVM RBF \\
\midrule
Training set CV \\[0.5ex]
Mean AUC         & 0.992  & 0.990  & 0.994 & 0.994 & 0.992   \\
Mean Sensitivity & 0.968  & 0.975  & 0.975 & 0.973 & 0.968   \\
Mean Specificity & 0.963  & 0.956  & 0.962 & 0.963 & 0.965   \\
Mean accuracy    & 0.966  & 0.966  & 0.968 & 0.968 & 0.966   \\
Mean avg.\ prec. & 0.979  & 0.973  & 0.980 & 0.981 & 0.968   \\
\addlinespace
Test 1 evaluation \\[0.5ex]
AUC         & 0.990  & 0.986  & 0.993 & 0.994 & 0.991   \\
Sensitivity & 0.928  & 0.936  & 0.928 & 0.936 & 0.936   \\
Specificity & 0.963  & 0.960  & 0.963 & 0.963 & 0.963   \\
F1 score    & 0.913  & 0.914  & 0.913 & 0.918 & 0.918   \\
Accuracy    & 0.945  & 0.948  & 0.945 & 0.949 & 0.949   \\
Avg.\ prec. & 0.970  & 0.951  & 0.975 & 0.976 & 0.970   \\
\addlinespace
Test 2 evaluation \\[0.5ex]
AUC         & 0.988  & 0.982  & 0.989 & 0.992 & 0.990   \\
Sensitivity & 0.937  & 0.945  & 0.945 & 0.945 & 0.937   \\
Specificity & 0.961  & 0.961  & 0.963 & 0.963 & 0.963   \\
F1 Score    & 0.915  & 0.920  & 0.923 & 0.923 & 0.919   \\
Accuracy    & 0.949  & 0.953  & 0.954 & 0.954 & 0.950   \\
Avg.\ prec. & 0.964  & 0.960  & 0.968 & 0.972 & 0.965   \\
\addlinespace
Test 3 evaluation \\[0.5ex]  
AUC         & 0.987  & 0.972  & 0.987 & 0.991 & 0.986   \\
Sensitivity & 0.913  & 0.921  & 0.921 & 0.937 & 0.921   \\
Specificity & 0.966  & 0.958  & 0.966 & 0.966 & 0.966   \\
F1 Score    & 0.910  & 0.903  & 0.914 & 0.922 & 0.914   \\
Accuracy    & 0.940  & 0.940  & 0.944 & 0.952 & 0.944   \\
Avg.\ prec. & 0.961  & 0.936  & 0.958 & 0.965 & 0.946   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of nice @mico answer (+1), where instead of `tabularx` package is used `tabularray`. With use it the MWE is (at least to my opinion) a wee bit more simple, concise and consistent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1]{%
    \SetCell[c=#1]{l, font=\bfseries\itshape,
                   cmd = \rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}
                   }
                            }% end of NewTableCommand


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Result of all evaluation metrics in \cite{lim2023robust}}
  \label{tab:tab1}
\begin{tblr}{colspec  = {@{} Q[l,rightsep+=4pt] 
                            *{4}{X[c]} 
                                 X[1.2, c] @{}},
             cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=5}{},
             row{3-Z}   = {rowsep=0.5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
Evaluation metric   &     Machine learning models             \\
    \midrule
                    & LR    & NB    & RF    & XGBoost   & SVM RBF   \\
\midrule
\subtitle{6} Training set CV \\
Mean AUC            & 0.992 & 0.990 & 0.994 & 0.994     & 0.992     \\
Mean Sensitivity    & 0.968 & 0.975 & 0.975 & 0.973 & 0.968   \\
Mean Specificity    & 0.963 & 0.956 & 0.962 & 0.963 & 0.965   \\
Mean accuracy       & 0.966 & 0.966 & 0.968 & 0.968 & 0.966   \\
Mean avg.\ prec.    & 0.979 & 0.973 & 0.980 & 0.981 & 0.968   \\
\subtitle{6} Test 1 evaluation \\
AUC                 & 0.990 & 0.986 & 0.993 & 0.994 & 0.991   \\
Sensitivity         & 0.928 & 0.936 & 0.928 & 0.936 & 0.936   \\
Specificity         & 0.963 & 0.960 & 0.963 & 0.963 & 0.963   \\
F1 score            & 0.913 & 0.914 & 0.913 & 0.918 & 0.918   \\
Accuracy            & 0.945 & 0.948 & 0.945 & 0.949 & 0.949   \\
Avg.\ prec.         & 0.970 & 0.951 & 0.975 & 0.976 & 0.970   \\
\subtitle{6} Test 2 evaluation \\
AUC                 & 0.988 & 0.982 & 0.989 & 0.992 & 0.990   \\
Sensitivity         & 0.937 & 0.945 & 0.945 & 0.945 & 0.937   \\
Specificity         & 0.961 & 0.961 & 0.963 & 0.963 & 0.963   \\
F1 Score            & 0.915 & 0.920 & 0.923 & 0.923 & 0.919   \\
Accuracy            & 0.949 & 0.953 & 0.954 & 0.954 & 0.950   \\
Avg.\ prec.         & 0.964 & 0.960 & 0.968 & 0.972 & 0.965   \\
\subtitle{6} Test 3 evaluation \\
AUC                 & 0.987 & 0.972 & 0.987 & 0.991 & 0.986   \\
Sensitivity         & 0.913 & 0.921 & 0.921 & 0.937 & 0.921   \\
Specificity         & 0.966 & 0.958 & 0.966 & 0.966 & 0.966   \\
F1 Score            & 0.910 & 0.903 & 0.914 & 0.922 & 0.914   \\
Accuracy            & 0.940 & 0.940 & 0.944 & 0.952 & 0.944   \\
Avg.\ prec.         & 0.961 & 0.936 & 0.958 & 0.965 & 0.946   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Style of the `subtitle` is based on one of my similar [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683226),  which someone can find a bit to exaggerated. However, style can be easily changed, for example as suggested @mico in our conversation to:

```
NewTableCommand\subtitle[1]{%
    \SetCell[c=#1]{l, font=\scshape,
                   cmd = \rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}
                   } 
                            }% end of NewTableCommand
```

which gives the following more appealing looks:

[image]

For an exercise on how a `subtitle' can be designed, another slightly exaggerated style:

```
\newcounter{ST}
\setcounter{ST}{0}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1]{%
    \stepcounter{ST}
    \ifnum\theST=1 \else    \midrule[dashed]    \fi
    \SetCell[c=#1]{l, font=\scshape,
                   cmd = \rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}
                   } 
                            }% end of NewTableCommand
```

which gives:

[image]

Of course, you can define own style according to your taste. I the most like @Mico suggestion.

Comment: @Mico, oh this is (big) error. When copy definition for `subloat` from similar table, I by mistake copy this caption to. I will correct asap ...

Comment: @mico, well my answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683226/), where a borrow part of code, has column headers in bold faces and gray background of  `subtitle`. Apparently there seems to be such selection of fonts appropriate or as has been OP desired :-)- I will edit answer asap and show more possibilities  how to design `subtitle`.